# Unable to call any function on spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a spark dataframe as a result of joining some other dataframes.

Now, calling any method on the dataframe fails.
It doesn't give specfic errors.
Only errors such as as ExecutorLostFailure, Slave lost, Container released on exited node.

I am not able to succesfully call even show() on dataframe.
Following is exception stack while calling show()

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 204 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 204.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 124823, ip-172-31-58-23.ec2.internal, executor 491): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 491 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1569)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1557)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1556)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1556)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1784)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1739)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1728)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:603)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:612)
    at com.example.DataCuration$.main(DataCurationMain.scala:81)
    at com.example.DataCuration.main(DataCurationMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

My guess is, i am running out of memory.
What are the best ways to determine if that is so?

Comment: w/o posting code it's very hard to answer this. Sometimes, this exception may hide a memory problem

Comment: ok. what are some general ways to log, the memory state in spark/scala code.

Comment: What's the deployment environment? What's the Spark version? Can you `head` on the Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was some issue with the machine.
Most probably low driver memory was constraining execution.